# Access Violation Reading Location when assigning Float (0x0000000000000170)

Tags: c++, access-violation, unreal-engine4

I'm crashing with a Access Violation reading location. I'm doing this in Unreal Engine, but it's simple and I feel the issue should be universally applicable within C++, though I am new to it.

I am crashing when trying to assign LastDoorOpenTime in OpenDoor() of OpenDoor.cpp (below). I'm able assign to it successfully at the start of the program in UOpenDoor::BeginPlay(), but trying the same thing in OpenDoor() crashes the application with "Access Violation reading location".

OpenDoor.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "Components/ActorComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Engine/TriggerVolume.h"
#include "Engine/World.h"
#include "OpenDoor.generated.h"


UCLASS( ClassGroup=(Custom), meta=(BlueprintSpawnableComponent) )
class ESCAPEROOM_API UOpenDoor : public UActorComponent
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this component's properties
    UOpenDoor();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    void OpenDoor();

    void CloseDoor();

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction) override;

private:
    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
        float OpenAngle = -60.f;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
        ATriggerVolume* PressurePlate;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
        float DoorCloseDelay = 1.f;

    float LastDoorOpenTime;

    AActor* ActorThatOpens;

    AActor* Owner;

    bool IsDoorOpen;

    UWorld* ThisWorld;
};
```

OpenDoor.cpp:

```
#include "OpenDoor.h"

// Sets default values for this component's properties
UOpenDoor::UOpenDoor()
{
    // Set this component to be initialized when the game starts, and to be ticked every frame.  You can turn these features
    // off to improve performance if you don't need them.
    PrimaryComponentTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // ...
}


// Called when the game starts
void UOpenDoor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    ThisWorld = GetWorld();
    ActorThatOpens = ThisWorld->GetFirstPlayerController()->GetPawn();
    AActor* Owner = GetOwner();
    IsDoorOpen = false;
}

void UOpenDoor::OpenDoor()
{
    Owner->SetActorRotation(FRotator(0.f, OpenAngle, 0.f));
    int cow = 1 + 1;
    LastDoorOpenTime = 0.f; //ACCESS VIOLATION HERE
    IsDoorOpen = true;
}

void UOpenDoor::CloseDoor()
{
    Owner->SetActorRotation(FRotator(0.f, 0.f, 0.f));
    IsDoorOpen = false;
}


// Called every frame
void UOpenDoor::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

    if (PressurePlate->IsOverlappingActor(ActorThatOpens)) {
        OpenDoor();
    }

    if (IsDoorOpen) {
        if (ThisWorld->GetTimeSeconds() >= LastDoorOpenTime + DoorCloseDelay) {
            CloseDoor();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the bug could be in this line `Owner->SetActorRotation(FRotator(0.f, OpenAngle, 0.f));`

Comment: Access Violations near address 0 usually mean a class member is being accessed via a null pointer. Check to make sure `OpenDoor()` is not being called via an invalid `UOpenDoor` object pointer.

Comment: Another problem I see is that `BeginPlay()` is assigning the return value of `GetOwner()` to a local variable named `Owner` instead of to the class member also named `Owner`.

Comment: That was it! As soon as I changed:
    AActor* Owner = GetOwner();
to:
    Owner = GetOwner();
everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

Changing: "AActor* Owner = GetOwner();" to "Owner = GetOwner();" fixed it.